# C# Visual Studio (Windows Forms) change color from designer with methods

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to put several customizing options to my windows form. To do so, I've made this: (It's a combo box)

```
    private void theme1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (theme1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            default:
                break;
            case 1:
                config p2 = new config();
                p2.browserinfo.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
                p2.confLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
                break;
        }
```

Its main purpose is to change the background color of these two elements, which are set in the config.Designer.cs (inside InitializeComponent()) as white by default:

```
 this.confLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
 this.browserinfo.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

However, apparently, my function does nothing. I've tried to put a MessageBox.Show there with a message to see if it was a calling problem but it isn't because the messagebox was shown... However, the color updating is not taking place.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Should  be noted too, that changing ANYTHING in the designer is risky, as it can be very easily overwritten accidentally.

Comment: If you mean written in form.designer.cs then DONT do that!

Comment: Where and when you call UpdateTheme method?

Comment: A very traditional bug is that you call UpdateTheme() on the wrong instance of the class.  Add `this.Show();` to the method, non-zero odds that you now see a new window with the updated colors :)

Comment: @hans-passant You're right! It's showing a new window with the updated colors :S So it seems I'm approaching this wrongly...

Comment: I'm curious why are you not setting this at form load, or on a given event trigger?

Comment: @user2366842 That is what I tried to do first, but as I couldn't get it to work I tried switching to what I've shown here...
Originally, I had that code inside a Combobox in another form, but I had the same problem, changes were not updating...

Comment: Modifying ANYTHING in the designer.cs is at best, dangerous grounds, as it gets overwritten the second you do so much as add a new label via drag/dropping it onto a form.  I'd go back to your original way of trying to solve the issue, and if you get stuck again, repost the question with the code at the point you get stuck.  The designer.cs file is rebuilt from scratch (which will wipe out your code changes) on every change to the form design.

Comment: @user2366842 Ok, I didn't know that, guess I will edit my question to show the other way I was trying to do it. Thank you very much.